# Programatically adding an image to Wagtail from one's local machine

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to add images to a model on my Wagtail site with a `manage.py` command. I found [this post that covers it](http://devans.mycanadapayday.com/programmatically-adding-images-to-wagtail/), but it's using a requests.get() call to the image from the internet. I have my images saved locally and have tried to adapt the linked code unsuccessfully:

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from wagtail.images.models import Image

path = f"{img_directory}/{filename}"
img_bytes = open(path, "rb").read()
img_file = ImageFile(BytesIO(img_bytes), name=filename)
img_obj = Image(title=filename, file=img_file)
print(img_obj.file)
img_obj.save()
```

The `print(img_obj.file)` statement does print the filename as defined, but when I try to call `img_obj.save()`, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: wagtailimages_image.width
```

I'm guessing that I'm opening the file wrong and it's not reading it as an image as I want it to, but I can't figure out where exactly I'm going wrong.

Comment: I have no way to test, but an ImageField is essentially just a path within the MEDIA_PATH.  So, you can technically just copy the file over there and then set `img_obj.file.path` to where it is.  You can then manually set `img_obj.file.width` and `img_obj.file.height`.  However, you're probably correct about it not working because it not being able to read the image file properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/40aedfc66b6605d1ece80c15ec38b37f028082a8/wagtail/images/fields.py#L97

You could probably do:

```
import willow
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from wagtail.images.models import Image

path = f"{img_directory}/{filename}"
img_bytes = open(path, "rb").read()
img_file = ImageFile(BytesIO(img_bytes), name=filename)

im = willow.Image.open(path)
width, height = im.get_size()

img_obj = Image(title=filename, file=img_file, width=width, height=height)
print(img_obj.file)
img_obj.save()
```

Comment: This got me on the right path to track down the issue, thank you for the response!

Comment: Yeah, I was wary that it was only a hint, not a full solution. I'm pleased to hear it helped. I couldn't quickly see where and how Wagtail does the equivalent on upload, but it can't be far off this.